# Using ternary operator to render correct template in component

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use conditional (ternary) operator to decide upon two template strings inside component's template property.

I am passing down list of jobs to my component:

```html
    <jobs :title="this.data.titles['experience']" :data="this.data.jobs"></jobs>
```

and here is my job and jobs component:

```html
    Vue.component('jobs', {
        props: ['title', 'data'],
        template: `<section id='jobs'>
            <header>{{ title }}</header>
            <job v-for="(job, index) in data" :job="job" :key="index"></job>
        </section>`    
    })

    Vue.component('job', {
        props: ['job'],
        template: job.hasOwnProperty('phases') && job.phases.length > 0 
            ? `<p>A</p>` 
            : `<p>B</p>`

    })
```

For some weird reason loop prints paragraph **A** even when list of jobs are:

```js
    [
      {
        "phases": [
          {
            "title": "Title 2"
          },
          {
            "title": "Title 1"
          }
        ],
        "workPlace": "Company B"
      },
      {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "workPlace": "Company A"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: You show the job component only not the jobs one,  
Also you can use props and the data section vars in a component template:  

    template: `<p>{{ job.hasOwnProperty('phases') && job.phases.length > 0 ? 'A' : 'B' }}</p>`

Comment: @Anatoly Pardon me, I forgot to add it.

Comment: Did you try  `template: <p>{{ job.hasOwnProperty('phases') && job.phases.length > 0 ? 'A' : 'B' }}</p>`?

Comment: @Anatoly This works if I am printing A's and B's but if I want to print collection of elements it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show an example with collection of elements instead of A's and B's?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't conditionally rendered templates like that before, so not sure if it's good practice.

If you do it like this, does it work?

```js
Vue.component('job', {
        props: ['job'],
        template: ` 
            <p v-if="job.hasOwnProperty('phases') && job.phases.length > 0">A</p>
            <p v-else>B</p>
        `
    })
```

Comment: Yes this solves my problem, but doesn't really answer my question. What do you mean by 'not sure if it's good practice'. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Well it doesn't make sense to conditionally render templates in that way. Vue expects the template to be clearly defined ahead of time.  That is specifically why `v-if` exists. I can't say for sure you should not do that as I haven't read it anywhere, but as you where having issues it would suggest so. Let's just say that the convention is to do it the way I demonstrated 